# Creating a 'View in Browser' link in Mailgun

Tags: mailgun

I've managed to create an email template and sending out email via the Mailgun API along with using the standard variables like the recipient details and the unsubscribe links.

But one thing we would like to offer to the user is the ability to view the email in their browser instead of in the email client. Does anyone know if this is possible out of the box? I've checked all the documentation and I cant see any way of achieving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, we ended up switching to sendgrid and found it a lot more easier.